# After bump ember-data from 2.13 to 2.14 the request payload not contain hasMany relations when the relation model had empty relation

Tags: serialization, ember.js, ember-data

with `ActiveModelSerializer` usage after the ember-data upgrade, the values of has_many case on the request payload had changed when the model has no records by relation, for example:

```
// app/models/user.js
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend(Validations, {
  posts: hasMany('post'),
...
}
```

```
// app/models/post.js
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import { belongsTo } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend(Validations, {
  user: belongsTo('user'),
...
}
```

so, if User has no posts, previously was sent `[]` into BE, but after `ember-data` bump to 2.14.11 no key-values sent, for example: (request payload)

Before:

```
user: { id: 1, post_ids: [] }
```

After:

```
user: { id: 1 }
```

Note:

```
"active-model-adapter": "2.2.0"
"ember-data": "2.14.11"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by: https://github.com/emberjs/data/compare/v2.14.3...v2.14.4

workaround: `app/serializers/application.js`

```
import EmbeddedRecordsMixin from 'ember-data/serializers/embedded-records-mixin';
import { ActiveModelSerializer } from 'active-model-adapter';
import { pluralize } from 'ember-inflector';

export default ActiveModelSerializer.extend(EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  isNewSerializerAPI: true,

  serializeHasMany(snapshot, model, relation) {
    this._super(...arguments);
    let relationKey = `${pluralize(relation.key.underscore()).slice(0, -1)}_ids`;
    if (relation.kind === 'hasMany' && !model[relationKey]) {
      model[relationKey] = Object.freeze([]);
    }
  }
});
```